# Bootstrap navbar collapsing upon clicking an option

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now but I can't seem to be able to locate the problem. Whenever I click on an option from the navbar, it collapses to mobile size (currently set to 992px in bootstrap so its available on tablets), and then return to original size, which turns out that it has a height of 80px after inspecting it. It used to be fine before, but it has suddenly changed after some code edits. I have included some pictures of the problem below.

[image: Before clicking any of the options]

[image: During the click]

[image: After the click]

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Navigation logo and dropdown icon -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="css/logo-dream.png" id="logo"></img></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation Options -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav-appearance">
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Below is the CSS code I have used:

```
/* Main navbar design */
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
  opacity: 0.95;
  background-color: #171717;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9494b8;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

/* Navbar company logo */
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 171px;
  height: 66px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

/* Navbar options */
#nav-appearance {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

#nav-appearance li {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.collapse {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  padding: 0;
}

/* ======= MEDIA QUERIES FOR NAVIGATION AND HOME ======= */

/* Tablets */
@media (max-width: 991px) {

  #nav-appearance {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  #nav-appearance a {
    padding: 0;
  }

  #nav-appearance li {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    width: 80%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 0;
    left: 52%;
  }

  #main-nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(55, 55, 55, .95);
  }

  #logo {
    content:url("home-icon-tiny.png");
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    margin-left: 13px;
  }
}

/* Mobile */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

  #logo {
    margin-left: 13px;
  }
}
```

Can anyone see any issues? I hope it's an easy fix.

Comment: Can post your markup as well.  Makes it hard to diagnose the issue without seeing what your markup is doing as well.

Comment: @filip a jsfiddle with the issue will be easy to debug

Comment: @jgetner Updated. Can't really do a jsfiddle because its a bootstrap navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

From the page its clear that one of the JS files is interfering with the navbar elements. By setting some CSS we can remove the height change, please find below the CSS.

**Codepen:** [here](https://codepen.io/kai1992cool/pen/XaZEOG)

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-brand img{
  margin-top:7px;
  margin-bottom:7px;
}

/* Navbar company logo */
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  height:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <!-- Navigation logo and dropdown icon -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="css/logo-dream.png" id="logo"></img></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation Options -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav-appearance">
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

From the images given I would say that this is a floating elements not having height issue, the solution for this is the clearfix class. so if you change the code as shown below it should not happen. also I removed the div with container-fluid class.

**Code:** (Do not use)

```
<!-- Navigation logo and dropdown icon -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="css/logo-dream.png" id="logo"></img></a>
</div>

<!-- Navigation Options -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav-appearance">
    <li id="main-nav"><a href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li id="main-nav"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    <li id="main-nav"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li id="main-nav"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately after these changes the problem still persists, as well as it makes some of the options on the navbar have no effects.

Comment: @FilipGrebowski In the codepen it seems fine, that's strange, if the page is available on the web we can check. One suggestion can you please add one more CSS to navbar-brand class `height:100%;` this will fix the issue mostly. I updated my codepen also

Comment: Hmm, still acts a bit wierd, it looks like it wants to close and can't. I've made the original problem available on the webiste: www.dream-home.co.uk

Comment: @FilipGrebowski After checking the website, the JS somewhere is messing with the navbar elements, was not able to find the place, I have provided CSS for fixing the navbar height change issue. Please find above my updated answer

Comment: Thats seems to fix it, however, upon clicking the links, they flash in a wierd way. Is there a fix for that? I've updated the webpage so you can see. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm, you have some strange script added, is it really needed, you need to remove these lines `<script>
      $('.nav a').on('click', function(){
        $('.btn-navbar').click(); //bootstrap 2.x
        $('.navbar-toggle').click() //bootstrap 3.x by Richard
      });
    </script>`, anyway bootstrap collapse works after removing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152299/discussion-between-filip-grebowski-and-naren-murali).